# How can I view a set timers countdown Angular 7

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

How can I view my timer's countdown when it's started? I've tried binding it to a variable but it comes up as `[object Object]`:

```js
setTime(time) {
    if (this.settime >= 5 ) {
      this.currentTime = time;
      this.alerttime = this.settime;
    this.notifiy.showInfo( 'Timer set for ' + this.settime + ' Minutes train is due in ' + time + ' Minutes' , '');
    const val = this.settime * 60000;
    const source = timer(val);
    this.time = source;
    console.log(this.time); // this prints out the observbale function Ive also tryed to bind it in the subscribe method but no joy.
    const subscribe = source.subscribe(value => { this.alertTimer(); });
    this.settime = '';
    //cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
    } else {
      this.notifiy.showFailure('You cant set the timer below 5 minutes', '');
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain what the parameter `i` is supposed to do? It doesn't occur in your `setTime()` implementation, only in the method signature.

Comment: Sorry typo fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "you cant" as the actual timer you are using does not have this property, as [per the documentation.](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer)

But depending on what you want to do with it, you probably want to keep track of the actual elapsed time separately, for this you could use "interval" instead.

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval

Say you set a `timer()` for 120 seconds, so it executes at the planned end. 
And then you use a separate `interval()` of 1s to keep track of elapsed time, and update UI etc, until the main timer has ended.

Pseudo-code, that shows the concept. From the top of my head, could have typos and such:

```
class TimerManager {

   private totalSeconds;
   private elapsedSeconds;

   private timerSub;
   private intervalSub

   // Start the timer
   public startTimer(timerLengthSeconds) {
      this.totalSeconds = timerLengthSeconds;
      var t = new timer(timerLengthSeconds);
      this.timerSub = t.subscribe(t => this.endTimer());
      var i = new interval(1000);
      this.intervalSub = i.subscribe(i => this.intervalElapsed());
   }

   // On each interval
   private intervalElapsed() {
      this.elapsedSeconds++;
      var remaining = this.totalSeconds - this.elapsedSeconds;
      console.log(this.elapsedSeconds + "s have elapsed, there are " + remaining + "s left");
   }

   // When the main timer ends
   private endTimer() {
     console.log("The time is up!!");
     this.intervalSub.unsubscribe();
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't completely understand, How I can get it to count down from the set time when I try it with the interval it counts up

Comment: well, thats just math, subtract the elapsed seconds from the total... I added an example to show my thoughts

Comment: First off thank you very very much for your answer its greatly appreciated, in the console when it is printing out the time elapsed it's coming up NaN

Comment: but it is counting the seconds correctly in the ammount of times it prints to the console

Comment: @conor I just wrote it of the top of my head so im sure it had errors - here it is working. The elapsedseconds had to initialize at 0: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5pw7b

Answer (score 0):

You can view timer countdown by checking the set interval function. Here is a example for that. You can use this even in Type Script. I think this could solve your problem.

```js
//120 Seconds timer...
var timeleft = 120;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  }
  timeleft -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: You can use  behaviour Subject Observable to and  update it  in the place of time left variable updating code by using next(timeleft). This could be your solution.